# What is the lowest possible process ID that a Linux process can have?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

On my system the lowest ID running right now is 1 (`init`). I'm making a small wrapper function around `pidof` and I was wondering, what is the lowest possible process ID a process can have?

The reason I ask is because I would like to return an integer from my function indicating "process was not running" (pidof itself returns an empty string in this case). I was thinking of using either 0 or -1, and I just want to make sure a real process could never have such IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIDs are always positive, so both 0 and -1 are OK as non-PID sentinels.  Several PID-related system calls, like `wait()` and `kill()`, assign special meaning to these values.